# SQL Query, how to select a interval where the next value is current value +1, identifying the next gap and leave everything else untouched?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a program on java using sql querys and i'd like to update a sequence of ids adding 1 to each, but only in the sequence interval.

Let's say i have a table like this:

> 1 - a | 2 - b | 3 - c | 5 - e | 6 - f

And i'd like to "push" a's ID and subsequents forward by 1, but only while the difference between one another is still 1. The result would be like this:

> 2 - a | 3 - b | 4 - c | 5 - e | 6 - f

I know it is possible to do programatically, but is there a way to do this with SQL querys? If not, what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Found the answer thanks to Thorsten Kettner, my query ended up like this:

```
update pair set id = id + 1 
where id >= 1 
and id < 
(
select min(id)
from (select * from pair) as gap
where gap.id > 1 and not exists
(
  select * 
  from (select * from pair) as oneless
  where oneless.id = gap.id - 1
)
)
order by id desc
```

Comment: 1 - a is the value for a field ?   if yes .. the pattern is always n - x ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying... a's column name would be something like "name"

Comment: So it could be any value. For instance, if i were to "push" from id 2 in 
> 1 - a | 2 - s | 3 - fernando | 6 - d | 7 - e

It would end like this: 
>1 - a | 3 - s | 4 - fernando | 6 - d | 7 - e

Comment: (Columns are separated with "-" and rows with "|", i don't know how to better repesent a table here, sorry)

Comment: Just a side note: If this is really the table's ID, then it should have no other meaning than identifying a record uniquely and one should never change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where the gap is that you want closed (ID 4 in your case) use this:

```
update mytable set id = id + 1 where id < 4;
```

If you don't know where the gap is, find it:

```
select min(id) - 1
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select * 
  from mytable oneless
  where oneless.id = mytable.id - 1
);
```

We can combine both statments now to do the update:

```
update mytable set id = id + 1 
where id <
(
  select min(id) - 1
  from mytable
  where not exists
  (
    select * 
    from mytable oneless
    where oneless.id = mytable.id - 1
  )
);
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! I was geting a "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause" but that was quick to solve, thanks a lot man/girl!

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your table Pair and the two columns Key and Value. Your query would be something like this:

```
update p1
set    Key = p1.Key + 1
from   Pair as p1
inner  join Pair as p2
on     p2.Key = p1.Key + 1
```

PS. I'm assuming your result has a typo because after the update, f should have a value of 7.

Comment: It has no typo... it would fill the space where there was no 4, that's why i said i wish to "push" the code and not just add everything by 1. Also, is your code right? I'm guessing it would be something like "update pair as p1 inner  join pair as p2
on     p2.codigo = p1.codigo + 1
set    p1.codigo = p1.codigo + 1" and even like this, i receive an error

Comment: Right, but why doesn't it "push" the code for "6 - f" since there is a "5 - e" before it? My code is for SQL Server. Looks like you are using MySQL? What is the error?

Comment: "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'"
I made a select to verify which ones it was trying to modify and with this condition, the row with "key" 3 is left untouched because of the inner join.

Also, i added the MYSQL tag but didn't specify inside the post, sorry for that too.

What i want to do is i want to limit it to the first break of sequence, where, in the first case, would be the 3 since there is no 4, and left all the rest untouched.

Comment: If i were to code it i would check row per row if the current "key" is equivalent to the previous +1 and stop when it's not, since it found an "empty space"